# how to get affiliated name in Admin sale order list?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

I need affiliated name in sale order list for corresponding orders on opencart.

I check the query on *admin/model/sale/order.php*

```
$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS order_status, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o";
```

I don't known how to add query for affiliate help me dudes.

Comment: Anyone please help me..  i need the query for that.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
`$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, (SELECT CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) FROM ". DB_PREFIX."affiliate a WHERE a.affiliate_id = o.affiliate_id ) as affiliate_name,  (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS order_status, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o";`
```

Comment: i had this error Error: Unknown column 'affiliate_name' in 'where clause' while filter the affiliate name in saleorderlist

Comment: In controller, Where do you want affiliate name?

Comment: i want it for order_list view.

Comment: do you want data based on affiliate name? Please specify exactly what you want.

Comment: My requirement is want a Orders by Affiliated name filter in sale order list.  and I had achieved with your query with slide modifications. Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: Can you please sent me the query for displaying product name in sale order list..

Comment: I had tried this query for product name.  but not works. => SELECT op.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id ) AS product_name

Comment: @aasikellahi, as there may be order contains more than one product it needs one more function in model to fetch all products in  a particular order and display it

Comment: try this 

    `foreach ($results as $result) {
   $product = array();
   $products = $this->model_cale_order->getOrderProducts($result['order_id']);
   foreach($products as $pro){
    $product[] = $pro['name']
   }
   $data['orders'][] = array(
    'products'  => $product,
    'order_id'      => $result['order_id'],
    'customer'      => $result['customer'],
    .....
`

Comment: Thank you, can i get mysql query?

Comment: there is no any query. I have used opencart's default function

Comment: i need to filter the order based on product too..  so that i need query..

Comment: its not possible as this code will fetch products on each order. Please go through the code you will understand

Comment: yes i understand, Radhika. But i had tried with this query it filters the order based on product.  => SELECT op.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id LIMIT 1) AS product_name   But takes more time to load the result.    :(

Comment: suppose,order_id = 1 has 3 product PRO1,PRO2 and PRO3. Now when orders are fetched (as per your query),whenever order_id=3 is being fetched it will go to order_product table to get product where order_id=3 so it will get 3 products PRO1,PRO2,PRO3 so how can it be return in PRODUCT_NAME in a single query. Are you getting my point?

Comment: yeah, now i understand.. so that i take more time to run.. i think.. Thank you. :)   Review my edit on our Answer ..